# Using only the first matrix of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, isin

I have an array that has two matrices in it. I am not bothered about the second matrix, just want the first one to use in a np.isin function. My function I am trying to run is listed below, and when I try run with the original array it comes up with the error 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()':

[image]

The new_data array is listed below, which I assume is where each value of the initial matrix is the line where 'combined_data' intersects with the line of the second matrix, which comes from flood. For example, the 9th line of the combined data intersects with the 106713rd line of the flood data. [image]

If I just took the first matrix of the array and inserted it into my initial line of code, would it work? I have tried np.vsplit but not sure how to work this, and even if so, if this would work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use image to show your code or errors.

Comment: You are using `new_data` as third parameter for `arange`, while it should be the second argument to `isin`

Comment: You would not believe how long I have spent on this... Thank you so much